# Html button link doesn't work

Tags: html

I am currently working on a logon box, but I am not sure how to make it into a working one as I'm new to coding, until I learn how, I am trying to get this code to go straight to a html page. The code I have right now for the button is:

code:

```
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
```

I would like the button as I said to go straight to a html page "OwnCloud.html"

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="your_link" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
 </form>
```

the input of type submit works with a form tag as a parent, so if you want to redirect to somewhere else your input tag needs to be inside a form.

**UPDATE**
  second alternative could be

```
<input type="submit" value="Redirect" onclick="window.location='your_link';" />
```

do you want to redirect to an external link or to a HTML page that is en your project?

Comment: And the server endpoint that handles `your_link` should either redirect to `OwnCloud.html` or directly echo it.

Comment: I tried this but it seems not to have worked, i forgot to add in the form part which i already had. when clicking `Login` it doesn't go anywhere still.

Comment: Tried the new one and still  no, it's weird as it goes to a page saying Unknown page. also trying to goto a Html page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a button to your form that is linked to the owncloud.html until you get the backend working.

```
  <a href="OwnCloud.html"><button type="button">Login</button></a>
```

Comment: thank you, seems to work now, I will use this for now, hopefully soon i will have the login working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login" onclick="location.href='OwnCloud.html'">
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Comment: I am having button named Login.while clicking on that button it open a specified html page.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist if i did anything wrong means correct me. i am new to this.

Comment: I'm just asking that you explain why the code solves the problem. That is much more useful than _just_ the code.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use the button type submit then you should put it inside a "form" tag and define an action for that form which in your case will be "OwnCloud.html"

Comment: Forgot to add the form part in with the rest of the code, so this isn't why it isn't working.